# Getting the lowest and highest number in a dictionary with nested list

Tags: python

Say if I have a dictionary like this (in the form [date, weight]):

```
dic = {'Pig': [['21-08-01', '67.12'], ['21-08-02', '65.32'], ['21-08-05', '55.56'], ['21-08-06', '59.49'], ['21-08-07', '58.63'], 'Cow': [['21-08-01', '140.23'], ['21-08-02', '135.12'], ['21-08-05', '131.35'], ['21-08-06', '182.42'], ['21-08-07', '145.30'], 'Horse': [...]] etc.
```

How do I find the highest and smallest number in this dictionary within the nested list? I want to find the lowest weight within the recent 30 days for each dictionary key, and then return that number.

I tried this:

```
    from operator import itemgetter
      # min of all elements
  mn = min(aktie_map, key=itemgetter(1))[1]

  # remove elements equal to min
  filtered = [x for x in aktie_map if x[1] != mn]

  # get min of remaining
  mn_fil = min(filtered,key=itemgetter(1))[1]

  # filter remaining
  out = [x for x in filtered if x[1] == mn_fil]
  print(out)
```

But it just prints out the key with the lowest number. And I am not so sure how that works. Does anyone have a good solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your input is invalid, and not just because of the "etc". Provide usable data and the expected result. And break it into readable several lines.

Comment: maybe better use normal `for`-loops and then you can put `print()` in this loop to see what you have in variables. And when normal `for`-loop will work then you may try to convert to list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict comprehension:

```py
dic = {'Pig': [['21-08-01', '67.12'], ['21-08-02', '65.32'], ['21-08-05', '55.56'], ['21-08-06', '59.49'], ['21-08-07', '58.63']], 'Cow': [['21-08-01', '140.23'], ['21-08-02', '135.12'], ['21-08-05', '131.35'], ['21-08-06', '182.42'], ['21-08-07', '145.30']]}

lowest = {k: min(map(lambda x: float(x[1]), v)) for k, v in dic.items()}
print(lowest) # {'Pig': 55.56, 'Cow': 131.35}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dic = {'Pig': [['21-08-01', '67.12'], ['21-08-02', '65.32'], ['21-08-05', '55.56'], ['21-08-06', '59.49'], ['21-08-07', '58.63']], 'Cow': [['21-08-01', '140.23'], ['21-08-02', '135.12'], ['21-08-05', '131.35'], ['21-08-06', '182.42'], ['21-08-07', '145.30']]}

for key in dic.keys():
    vals = [float(item[1]) for item in dic[key]]
    minval = min(vals)
    print('Key: ', key, 'Mininum value = ',minval)
```

For the above, I get this output:

```
Key:  Pig Mininum value =  55.56
Key:  Cow Mininum value =  131.35
```

Essentially, you are creating a list of the [1] item (i.e., the weight) in each of the sublists and then taking the minimum of this list.
Likewise, use "max" to find the max.

Comment: I wish downvoters explained what they had in mind. I didn't downvote this, but I guess the reason might be that you didn't convert `item[1]` to a number; the code works for the given example, but if you compare `'50'` with `'100'` for example, the code will say `'100'` is smaller than `'50'`.

Comment: Good point. I did forget to float() it. I made the edit. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np

dic = {'Pig': [['21-08-01', '67.12'], ['21-08-02', '65.32'], 
               ['21-08-05', '55.56'], ['21-08-06', '59.49'], 
               ['21-08-07', '58.63']],
       'Cow': [['21-08-01', '140.23'], ['21-08-02', '135.12'], 
              ['21-08-05', '131.35'], ['21-08-06', '182.42'],
              ['21-08-07', '145.30']]
       }

print('animal min max')
for a in dic:
    arr = np.array(dic[a])
    mn = min(arr[:,1])
    mx = max(arr[:,1])
    print(a, mn, mx)
```